# How can I hide empty grid columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm using bootstrap to make a responsive template for a CMS. I want to have a three column grid in the main area, but sometimes, there isn't content in all three columns. The CMS will add a class to any column that is empty, so I can use that to hide them, but I can't get bootstrap to expand the other two columns to fill the area.

So, if I have three columns that are all col-md-4, but one is hidden, I basically want the others to become col-md-6. If two are empty, I'd want the remaining one to be col-md-12. But, I haven't had any luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Since the addition of flexbox to Bootstrap 4, you can use the `.col` class to automatically size the column widths.  Using the `:empty` pseudo selector (or if you wanted, a custom class like `.col-empty`) you can hide columns with no content.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/manafire/pen/pOrRjE)

More about [Bootstrap Column Layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#all-breakpoints)
Also, [Empty Pseudo Selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/) - must be empty element!

```css
.row { margin: 25px 0; }
.col1 { background-color: red; }
.col2 { background-color: lightgreen; }
.col3 { background-color: gold; }

/* ways of hiding the column if no content */
.col-empty, .col:empty, [class^=col-]:empty { display: none; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col1">ONE</div>
    <div class="col col2">TWO</div>
    <div class="col col3">THREE</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col1">ONE</div>
    <div class="col col2"></div>
    <div class="col col3">THREE</div>
  </div> 
  
    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col1"></div>
    <div class="col col2"></div>
    <div class="col col3">THREE</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. This is especially useful in CMS systems like dotnetnuke where you don't always know if there will be any content in columns because users add their content in columns.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    if ($('.sideBar').is(':empty')) {
        $('.sideBar').remove()
        $('.myContent').removeClass('col-md-9').addClass('col-md-12');
    }
});

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 sideBar">menu</div>
    <div class="col-md-9 myContent"></div>
</div>
```

You could fully automate this, here is start, anyone likes to continue for me? :)

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $('.row').each(function() {
    var row = $(this);    
    row.children().each(function () {
      var col = $(this);
      if col.is(':empty')
      {
        col.remove();
       /*TODO: we need to first count all empty cols, then divide those among non empty cols by changing their style*/
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'd use PHP (or your particular server-side language) logic to apply the appropriate Bootstrap classes depending on whether there's content in the column or not. This probably shouldn't be done with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the same logic you applied the css styles to add bootstrap css classes such as "col-md-6". Like any styles, bootstrap styles can be added or removed on demand.