# bootstrap 3 columns (hide empty col)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have html code on my site:

```
<div id="main" class="col-md-9 col-xs-12"></div>
<div id="right" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12"></div>
```

It's possible to hide 'right' column if empty in 'md' size ? And resize 'main' to col-md-12
thx

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the tag is empty with Javascript and then hide the element.

```
function myfunc(){
  var rightDiv = document.getElementById("right").value;
  if(rightDiv == ""){
    rightDiv.style.visibility="hidden";
  }
}

window.onload=myfunc;
```

Comment: Maybe, PHP is a server-side response.  For instance, if I click X, then the form tells PHP I clicked X, and then PHP can render a new document with nothing in the `<div id="right">` ... but I suspect that isn't the interaction you are seeking?

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question : [Bootstrap 3 - hide empty grid column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339540/bootstrap-3-hide-empty-grid-column)

> Normally you'd use PHP (or your particular server-side language) logic to apply the appropriate Bootstrap classes depending on whether there's content in the column or not. This probably shouldn't be done with CSS.

(You could also use JavaScript/jQuery)